# VOIP application running in background stops after a few hours

Tags: ios, ios7, voip, pjsip

We have created a VOIP app using PJSIP and implemented background running which works fine for a few hours.  After that it stops working (it no longer receives calls).

Has anyone else had this issue?  I believe it is only in ios7

PJSIP TCP socket is tagged as VOIP

```
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
{
    // Use this method to release shared resources, save user data, invalidate timers, and store enough application state information to restore your application to its current state in case it is terminated later. 
    // If your application supports background execution, this method is called instead of applicationWillTerminate: when the user quits.


    [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(keepAlive) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:YES];
    [application setKeepAliveTimeout:600 handler: ^{
        [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(keepAlive) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:YES];
    }];

}

- (void)keepAlive {
    int i, timeout = KEEP_ALIVE_INTERVAL;

    if (!pj_thread_is_registered())
    {
        pj_thread_register("ipjsua", a_thread_desc, &a_thread);
    }

    for (i = 0; i < (int)pjsua_acc_get_count(); ++i) {
        if (pjsua_acc_is_valid(i)) {
            pjsua_acc_config acc_cfg;

            pjsua_acc_get_config(i, &acc_cfg);
            if (!acc_cfg.reg_uri.slen)
                continue;
            if (acc_cfg.reg_timeout < timeout) {
                acc_cfg.reg_timeout = timeout;
                pjsua_acc_modify(i, &acc_cfg);
            } else {
                pjsua_acc_set_registration(i, PJ_TRUE);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried running a capture like WireShark to see if the device is getting the SIP INVITE message?  I've found some networks may close the background TCP connection in less than 10 minutes -- before you have a chance to wakeup and send a keep-alive.  If your gatekeeper has the ability to poll the device over the TCP connection, it might be enough to keep the socket alive.  Unfortunately 600 seconds is the shortest interval Apple will allow. https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/qa/qa1176/_index.html

Comment: Thanks for trying to help mate, the odd bit is its after like 3-4 hours??

Comment: Could it be the os shutting down the app for more memory, it uses very little but could that be it?  I had read that skype uses APN's to wake it up